# Is there a way to redirect to a different website by using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using canvas and I want to be able to redirect someone to a different website if they click a certain part of the page. I know that I can use onClick for part of this, but I want to be able to redirect to a different page.

Comment: any previous research you have done? Some code maybe?

Comment: In the mousedown event handler: (1) get the mouse position relative to the canvas, (2) Use the mouse position to determine which URL (website) you want to go to, (3) Open a new browser tab with: `window.open('www.desiredWebsite.com','_blank');
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the user navigate to a different url, use

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com";
```

By the way, this is not a HTML5 feature. It's standard Javascript for over a decade.